# Github GraphQL API Get all commits of a User

Tags: graphql, github-api, github-api-v4

I'm trying to use the GitHub GraphQL API to get all the additions made by a user (additions can be found from their commits). I've been able to get the additions from pull requests, but I haven't found a way to do the same for commits. How can I get all the commits from a user?

This is my query (I am new to GraphQL):

```graphql
query AllAdditions($username: String!, $from: DateTime, $to: DateTime) {
  user(login: $username) {
    name
    contributionsCollection(from: $from, to: $to) {
      commitContributionsByRepository(maxRepositories: 100) {
        repository {
          nameWithOwner
        }
        contributions(first: 30) {
          totalCount
          # I'm trying to get additions like this, but there is no 'commit' field    
          # nodes {
          #   commit {
          #     additions
          #   }
          # }
        }
      }
      pullRequestContributionsByRepository(maxRepositories: 100) {
        repository {
          nameWithOwner
        }
        contributions(first: 30) {
          nodes {
            pullRequest {
              additions
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Contributions` provided by the API don't contain a reference to the commit and are not really useful for this purpose.

I ended up with the following query to first get the repositories the user has contributed to and then the commits for each repository where the author email matches.

Edit: I just found out that the `repositoriesContributedTo` endpoint only lists the repositories the user has contributed to in the last year. So this approach doesn't really work as intended but still could be useful. More information:

- https://github.com/anuraghazra/github-readme-stats/issues/2269
- https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/39589

You can test the query here: https://docs.github.com/de/graphql/overview/explorer.

```
query (
  $cursorRepo: String,
  $cursorCommit: String,
  $user: String = "username",
  $emails: [String!] = ["author@example.com", "author@example2.com"]
) {
  user(login: $user) {
    repositoriesContributedTo(
      includeUserRepositories: true
      contributionTypes: COMMIT
      first: 100
      after: $cursorRepo
    ) {
      totalCount
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
      nodes {
        name
        defaultBranchRef {
          target {
            ... on Commit {
              history(author: {emails: $emails}, after: $cursorCommit) {
                totalCount
                pageInfo {
                  hasNextPage
                  endCursor
                }
                nodes {
                  ... on Commit {
                    oid
                    messageHeadline
                    committedDate
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine for me unless the checked user is a Linux Kernel contributor. That repository causes some problems and I only get HTTP 502 error codes from the server. It works for all the other projects I have contributed to, though.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. If I remember correctly I was trying to find the number of lines of code that Linus Torvalds had written (for some reason which I don't remember, seems very impractical in hindsight) so this wouldn't work for that but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [lee-dhom](https://github.com/lee-dohm) in [GraphQL - Get all commits by all users](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/24590#discussioncomment-3244575):

> ```
> {
>   search(query: "org:test", type: REPOSITORY, last: 100) {
>     nodes {
>       ... on Repository {
>         name
>         defaultBranchRef {
>           name
>           target {
>             ... on Commit {
>               history(first: 100, since: "2013-07-11T00:00:00") {
>                 totalCount
>                 nodes {
>                   ... on Commit {
>                     committedDate
>                     additions
>                     author {
>                       name
>                       email
>                     }
>                   }
>                 }
>               }
>             }
>           }
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> As for getting all orgs, there isn’t currently a way to do that via
> the GraphQL API because the search connection requires something in
> the search query. There’s also no top-level connection that allows you
> to list all users, orgs, or repositories.
>
> I hope that helps!